# Positon css border under text and under image

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I'm trying to get this effect with the border under the text and image.

[image: Example]

My code so far looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="grid-child" id="imageContainer">
     <div class="borderImage"></div>
     <img src="src" border="0" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.borderImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: -1; // just makes the border disappear.
}

.borderImage:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: -36%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: add positon:relative and z-index:0; to imageContainer

Comment: It doesn't do anything everything is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#imageContainer {
  height: 800px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 15%;
}

.borderImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: -1; // just makes the border disappear.
}

.borderImage:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 25%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #cccccc;
  border-right: 4px solid #cccccc;
}
```

and check the example i made in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/LaKhDaR/auewovfr/118/